# AngularJS: sessionStorage variables not erased upon full cache clear

Tags: angularjs, session, caching

Right now I'm using Session Storage to store user information upon logging in. As expected the Session variables persist even after a page refresh. When you close the window and log back in, as expected, the Session Storage variables no longer exist. However, if a user refreshes with CTRL + F5, clearing cache, the Session Storage variables do persist, yet they empty out.

This is bad for me for one single reason: One of my session variables are a boolean, and it resets to true while it should surely be false unless they're logged in. What's the way around this? And please, before trying to give me an answer that involves anything other than sessionStorage, believe me that I'm not using it by choice.

```
    .factory('Session',['$window', function ($window){
      memorizeLogged : function(val) {
            try { 
                if($window.Storage){
            $window.sessionStorage.setItem('LoggedIn',       
            $window.JSON.stringify(val));
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } catch(error){
          console.error(error, error.message);
        }
        return false;
      },

      isLogged: function(){
            try {
                if($window.Storage){
            return 
          $window.JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('LoggedIn'));
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } catch(error){
          console.error(error, error.message);
        }
        return false;
      }
 }
```

I was looking for a way to set the boolean to false upon detecting a combination of key presses, but that sounds like a very dirty solution.

edit: The only other thing I thought of was simply making every check for the variable in Angular reversed, so I'm checking for false instead of true, but that - again - sounds like a dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a boolean just switch to an int with either 0 or 1. Your value checks will be a little different, but 0/1 can probably get you the same results as false/true

Also, when you say empty out I'm assuming you mean they are uninitialized?

Comment: They're initialized, simply with empty values. I think your solution might be the only.

Comment: In your own language, I don't think there's going to be a clean solution for this necessarily.